# Which segment of the ELF file should the static int variable be loaded into?

Tags: c, elf

I met a question when I tried to finish my operating system lab.
I was asked to write an MBR Bootloader program and I have already finish it, but there's a comment in the frame code saying that "DO NOT DEFINE ANY NON-LOCAL VARIABLE!".
I use the command "readelf -s/-S", trying to find the reason. It is stipulated in the experiment manual that kernel's ELF file is loaded to the location of 0x8000.
I've defined a global variable haha, the result is as follows.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
We can see the haha is in section 2(.bss), and its location coincides with the starting location of the kernel's ELF file, so it may corrupt the kernel's ELF file, or the kernel's ELF file will change its value.

Then something strange happened.
I change haha's type to static int, use the same commands above, it disappeared in the symbol table!!!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
From what I've learned, a static-qualified symbol is a local static symbol, and it should be placed in a .data or .bss section, but it simply disappears, and there is no .data section or .bss section in the section header table.
So do I misunderstand something wrong, or is there some knowledge gap that I don't know about?

I put all the operations I did in the problem description. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Please don't show pictures of text. Cut/paste the text itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you use an optimizing compiler, which decided that an unused variable local to the translation unit can be removed.

Without `static`, the variable has "*external linkage*". In simple words this means that this variable is visible globally in your program. The compiler must not drop it, and the linker allocates space for it.

With `static`, the variable has "*internal linkage*". In simple words this means that this variable is only visible inside the source file. The compiler can deduce that you don't access it, and can therefore drop it for optimization.

*Note: A translation unit is (in simple words) your source and its includes.*